# where can i get a aviation map of korea with the moes, and highways and vectors

Tags: navigation, flight-planning, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aeronautical-charts, south-korea

ive been searching for a aviation map of South Korea and cant find anyone that sells it. does anyone know where I can find one for flight planning

Comment: What is "moes"?

Comment: My bad i meant to say moa

Comment: You can use edit button to edit any of your post.

Comment: Data location is off topic as defined by the [help center](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Those are available in section ENR 6 of the [South Korean AIP](http://ais.casa.go.kr/). [Direct link](http://ais.casa.go.kr/pdf.asp?file=ENR%206.1_181207.pdf&midcode=62&BigCode=12&GubunCode=2).

Comment: But you have to be able to read Korean, and Google Translate won't work because of the way they display their text. Also, the direct link is not responding.

Comment: Ah, the direct link is responding now, but about as slow as molasses on a winter day in Pluto. :)

Comment: @JuanJimenez You don't need to read Korean, just click the big button that says "AIP" in the top left corner. Their AIP follows the international standard format used in pretty much every country all over the world, so it's extremely easy to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one for free [here](http://legacy.lib.utexas.edu/maps/onc/txu-pclmaps-oclc-8322829_g_10.jpg) but I have no idea if it is legal to use for air navigation.